# Hosting multiple Plumber APIs on a single EC2 instance using multiple ports?

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, plumber

Following R's very good Plumber documentation, as well as getting help from [this helpful link](http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2017/09/plumber-api-on-aws/), I was able to set up a single R API on an EC2 instance using the Plumber library, with a couple of endpoints.

I have this API on port 8000 of the EC2 instance, and to confirm, if I check the processes in my EC2 instance, I can see my R API on Port 8000:

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-45-67-890 ~]$ lsof -i tcp:8000
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
R       16784 ec2-user   11u  IPv4 152626      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

I would like to launch a second API on this same EC2 server, and my question is, can I use other ports on the EC2 server to serve the APIs? For example, in my R files for the new API that "plumbs" the API, I would simply change the port to 8001:

```
# clear workspace and load library
rm(list = ls())
library(plumber)

# serve API
r <- plumb("NBA_API.R")
r$run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8001)
```

and additionally, for the EC2 instance, change the security groups so that port 8001 can be accessed.

Is doing this (using different ports) okay, or am I going to mess up the EC2 instance by trying to host multiple APIs each on different ports? I'd like to know this before I mess up my current API.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

EDIT - also, if its okay to use port 8001, does that mean I can pretty much use any port to serve additional APIs (8002, 8003, 8004, etc.). Are there any ports I should not use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That shouldn't be a problem. You can host as many of these as you want on arbitrary ports. You'll just need to make sure that the security group allows traffic through to your machine and, if applicable, the machine's local firewall also allows traffic in.

Do be aware, though, that running R natively on the server isn't optimal. If the R process were ever to crash (e.g. due to a bug in your code that can get tripped up in unlikely scenarios) it wouldn't automatically restart. Likewise, if the server ever needs rebooting, you'll need to manually spin up the appropriate processes on the appropriate ports to get things running again.

You can take a look at some of the hosting options mentioned in https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html for ideas about how to host plumber in a more "productiony" way. I don't specifically address EC2 in the docs, but some of those patterns (including PM2) should work just fine on an EC2 machine.